# How do I get the angularJS routeProvider to perform an action before the route change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have this config:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', { 
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/index.html',
            controller: 'defaultCtrl'
        })
        .when('/other', {
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/other.html',
            controller: 'errorCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({ 
            templateUrl: 'app/partials/404.html'
        });
  }
]);
```

I'm looking for a place to do some basic, common maintenance code before the router calls the route. Say I'd like to clear the console log via `console.clear()` every time the route is changed. How and where would be the best place in the code to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `$route` service raise events like `$routeChangeStart` which you can use to perform such tasks. You can implement them using the $scope.$on method. Someting like

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart',function(angularEvent,next,current) {
  //do you work here
});
```

Read the `$route` [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute.%24route) to get idea on this and other such events.

Also `$routeProvider` configuration method `when` also can take a parameter `resolve` which actually is used to setup dependencies before the route is resolved. This `resolve` object map can also be used to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, where do I put this, though?

Comment: You can add the the $routeChangeStart even handler is any controller. The practice is to add this event handler on a controller which is defined outside the `ng-view` such as `mainController` or `rootController`

Comment: if you want to add the event on rootscope you should do this inside module.run section